# Moving from Bower to Yarn asp.net Core 1.1 visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gulp, bower, yarnpkg

I took over a ASP.NET CORE 1.1 project which was using bower and gulp that's hosted on azure web app. Since bower is discontinued I decided to move to yarn.

I got Yarn installed after and moving bower.json items to package.json I thought all would be fine. I noticed the js files downloaded goes into node_modules not in wwwroot/lib folder. I think I need to use gulp to build the library and dist folders. But I am pretty much stuck at this point.

Also started getting this:

> The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(s): projectname\tsconfig.

Added tsconfig.json with suggested code in it, but it didn't solve the problem. I got the project working by grabbing copy of wwwroot from server.

But need to solve these issues.